# CQL query with QUORUM consistency returning large result set

Tags: cassandra, cql

We have a CQL query that returns around 8000 rows. We see occasional query timeouts due to QUORUM consistency not met. After doing some investigation, we are suspecting this is because one or more rows are constantly changing so Cassandra can't get QUORUM consistency on some rows in given 10 seconds (rpc timeout). I wanted to reach out to Cassandra dev community and ask if anyone had success in using QUORUM consistency on queries that return large result set while rows are constantly changing or are we left with using consistency of ONE only?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What client are you using to query those rows?

Comment: Datastax Java client 2.1.6

Answer (score 0):

The fact that rows are changing doesn't seem to be the problem here. 
Getting a Quorum doesn't mean getting up to date data from a quorum, but just getting answers from a quorum. If data doesn't match through the quorum, timestamps will decide on which data "wins" and gets returned.

Quorum queries on 8000 rows should be no problem with a proper data model (you can extract hundreds of thousands rows with quorum consistency, if not more).

Try to set a rather small page size (100 records), and split your query in one asynchronous query per partition.
Also check if your nodes aren't overloaded when you get timeouts.

Give us your table model and query if you want more insights on what to improve, as well as how you're accessing data (which language, driver, etc...)